# Style Guide for Mobile Web Development

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

I am developing mobile version of websites and I am interested in following best practices in terms of style guide and specs for iPhone and Android. Is there an official document or a good resources online that I can refer to?

For example, I would like to know how much space should I have in between vertical buttons, what's the recommended minimum size of a font, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both apple and android have a lot of information. Look at their respective sites:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

and

http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

These are for native apps, but the html apps should follow the same 'rules'

happy reading.